# Sorting An Array Of Objects Based On Time And Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an object with the following structure:

```
var jsonData = {
    "1":["Test Event 1","5","interview","08:30:00","2016-05-28","1"],
    "2":["Test 2","2","Lesser Important Items","08:30:00","2016-05-27","0"],
    "3":["Test Event 4","5","meeting","08:30:00","2016-06-12","1"],
    "4":["","0","Lesser Important Items","08:30:00","2016-06-12","0"],
    "5":["","0","Lesser Important Items","08:30:00","2016-06-12","0"],
    "6":["Test Event 3","1","interview","19:30:00","2016-05-29","1"]
 }
```

I wanted to sort this on the basis of the time and date, and this is what I tried:

```
jsonData.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.time - b.time;
})
```

but this is returning an error stating:

```
jsonData.sort is not a function
```

Comment: it's an  object, not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** method can only apply applied to array, the provided data is an object.

If you just want the sorted index array

```js
var data = {
  "1": ["Test Event 1", "5", "interview", "08:30:00", "2016-05-28", "1"],
  "2": ["Test 2", "2", "Lesser Important Items", "08:30:00", "2016-05-27", "0"],
  "3": ["Test Event 4", "5", "meeting", "08:30:00", "2016-06-12", "1"],
  "4": ["", "0", "Lesser Important Items", "08:30:00", "2016-06-12", "0"],
  "5": ["", "0", "Lesser Important Items", "08:30:00", "2016-06-12", "0"],
  "6": ["Test Event 3", "1", "interview", "19:30:00", "2016-05-29", "1"]
};


var res = Object.keys(data) // get object keys array
  .sort(function(a, b) { // sort the key array based on the date and time
    // convert to date and get difference for sorting
    return new Date(data[a][4] + ' ' + data[a][3]) - new Date(data[b][4] + ' ' + data[b][3]);
  })

console.log(res)
```

---

Or if you want to convert it to a sorted array based on the time and date then do something like this,

```js
var data = {
  "1": ["Test Event 1", "5", "interview", "08:30:00", "2016-05-28", "1"],
  "2": ["Test 2", "2", "Lesser Important Items", "08:30:00", "2016-05-27", "0"],
  "3": ["Test Event 4", "5", "meeting", "08:30:00", "2016-06-12", "1"],
  "4": ["", "0", "Lesser Important Items", "08:30:00", "2016-06-12", "0"],
  "5": ["", "0", "Lesser Important Items", "08:30:00", "2016-06-12", "0"],
  "6": ["Test Event 3", "1", "interview", "19:30:00", "2016-05-29", "1"]
};


var res = Object.keys(data) // get object keys array
  .sort(function(a, b) { // sort the key array based on the date and time
    // convert to date and get difference for sorting
    return new Date(data[a][4] + ' ' + data[a][3]) - new Date(data[b][4] + ' ' + data[b][3]);
  }).map(function(v) { // use map to generate the object array
    return data[v] // get object from the data
  });

console.log(res)
```

---

In case if you want to re-index based the object keys then do something like this using sorted object array

```js
var data = {
  "1": ["Test Event 1", "5", "interview", "08:30:00", "2016-05-28", "1"],
  "2": ["Test 2", "2", "Lesser Important Items", "08:30:00", "2016-05-27", "0"],
  "3": ["Test Event 4", "5", "meeting", "08:30:00", "2016-06-12", "1"],
  "4": ["", "0", "Lesser Important Items", "08:30:00", "2016-06-12", "0"],
  "5": ["", "0", "Lesser Important Items", "08:30:00", "2016-06-12", "0"],
  "6": ["Test Event 3", "1", "interview", "19:30:00", "2016-05-29", "1"]
};


Object.keys(data) // get object keys array
  .sort(function(a, b) { // sort the key array based on the date and time
    // convert to date and get difference for sorting
    return new Date(data[a][4] + ' ' + data[a][3]) - new Date(data[b][4] + ' ' + data[b][3]);
  }).map(function(v) { // use map to generate the object array
    return data[v] // get object from the data
  }).forEach(function(v, i) {
    data[i + 1] = v; // update based on the sorted array
  })

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant sort object but you can sort array of object keys

```js
var obj = {
  "1": ["Test Event 1", "5", "interview", "08:30:00", "2016-05-28", "1"],
  "2": ["Test 2", "2", "Lesser Important Items", "08:30:00", "2016-05-27", "0"],
  "3": ["Test Event 4", "5", "meeting", "08:30:00", "2016-06-12", "1"],
  "4": ["", "0", "Lesser Important Items", "08:30:00", "2016-06-12", "0"],
  "5": ["", "0", "Lesser Important Items", "08:30:00", "2016-06-12", "0"],
  "6": ["Test Event 3", "1", "interview", "19:30:00", "2016-05-29", "1"]
}

var sort = Object.keys(obj).sort(function(a, b) {
  return Date.parse(obj[a][4]) - Date.parse(obj[b][4]) || Date.parse(obj[a][3].replace(/:/g, ' ')) - Date.parse(obj[b][3].replace(/:/g, ' '));
})

console.log(sort)
```

Then you can use that sorted array to get object values [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/909/)

Answer (score 1):

Your json object is not well formated, it should be something like :

```
{
    {
       "even_id":"1",
       "event_name":"Test Event",
       "event_watever":"1",
       "event_time":"08:30:00",
       "event_date":"2016-05-28"
    },
    {
       "even_id":"2",
       "event_name":"Test Event2",
       "event_watever":"5",
       "event_time":"08:30:00",
       "event_date":"2016-05-28"
    }
}
```

And, with that, you loop over each event and you sort them by event_date ( + event_time if date are equals) in a new Array.

Comment: isnt there any other way to do it without formatting, i am getting this array from my server script

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is not an array it is an object. You need to convert this to array first.

```
var obj = {
    "1":["Test Event 1","5","interview","08:30:00","2016-05-28","1"],
    "2":["Test 2","2","Lesser Important Items","08:30:00","2016-05-27","0"],
    "3":["Test Event 4","5","meeting","08:30:00","2016-06-12","1"],
    "4":["","0","Lesser Important Items","08:30:00","2016-06-12","0"],
    "5":["","0","Lesser Important Items","08:30:00","2016-06-12","0"],
    "6":["Test Event 3","1","interview","19:30:00","2016-05-29","1"]
 }
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){ return [key, obj[key]] });
```

Now you can sort it on the date and time as

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){ 
  var da = a[1][4], ta = a[1][3], db = b[1][4], tb = b[1][3];  
  da = da.split("-").map(function(val){ return parseInt(val,10); }); 
  ta = ta.split(":").map(function(val){ return parseInt(val,10); });
  db = db.split("-").map(function(val){ return parseInt(val,10); }); 
  tb = tb.split(":").map(function(val){ return parseInt(val,10); });

  var dateA = new Date( da[0], da[1]-1, da[2], ta[0], ta[1], ta[2] );
  var dateB = new Date( db[0], db[1]-1, db[2], tb[0], tb[1], tb[2] );
  return dateA.getTime() -dateB.getTime();
})
```

**DEMO**

```js
var obj = {
    "1":["Test Event 1","5","interview","08:30:00","2016-05-28","1"],
    "2":["Test 2","2","Lesser Important Items","08:30:00","2016-05-27","0"],
    "3":["Test Event 4","5","meeting","08:30:00","2016-06-12","1"],
    "4":["","0","Lesser Important Items","08:30:00","2016-06-12","0"],
    "5":["","0","Lesser Important Items","08:30:00","2016-06-12","0"],
    "6":["Test Event 3","1","interview","19:30:00","2016-05-29","1"]
 }
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){ return [key, obj[key]] });

arr.sort(function(a,b){ 
  var da = a[1][4], ta = a[1][3], db = b[1][4], tb = b[1][3];  
  da = da.split("-").map(function(val){ return parseInt(val,10); }); 
  ta = ta.split(":").map(function(val){ return parseInt(val,10); });
  db = db.split("-").map(function(val){ return parseInt(val,10); }); 
  tb = tb.split(":").map(function(val){ return parseInt(val,10); });

  var dateA = new Date( da[0], da[1]-1, da[2], ta[0], ta[1], ta[2] );
  var dateB = new Date( db[0], db[1]-1, db[2], tb[0], tb[1], tb[2] );
  return dateA.getTime() -dateB.getTime();
})
console.log(arr);
```